# Matter (CHIP) controller/bridge implementation linux c++

Tags: c++, zigbee, matter-iot-standard

I'm trying to develop a matter [(https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip/)](https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip/) controller/bridge in order to be able to control matter compatible devices within a linux daemon.

I was thinking that matter could be like any other library to me, they generate a library to link and a set of public headers to compile.

If I see the code in github and compile all the stuff in there, we could see libraries and examples, but there is no documentation about the API (besides of the examples) and if you try to copy an example to outside the repository and try to compile it resolving all references to inside, seems that you need the full source code to compile.

Seems like everything is oriented to develop final devices, with specific boards vendors, but, which is the way to implement something like bridges or controller? seems that everything is developed to create applications inside the own matter repo. Is this the way? is there any reason to do it like this? I would like to understand how is built and how to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right about the matter project and its documentation. There is no even simple example how to develop a custom controller.  I had to open an issue to ask questions about the project. But if you want to understand how it is built and how to integrate, then look at https://github.com/project-chip/matter.js . This matter.js has discussion section on github  and discord. https://github.com/project-chip/matter.js/discussions or  https://discord.gg/ujmRNrhDuW . It is javascript project, but you can ask questions to understand how it is built.